# String-to-byte sequence translation using a fixed encoding, preferably UTF-8

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, codepages

In a windows c++ console application I would like to read a password from command-line input. The password is used for encryption (and later decryption, maybe elsewhere in the world on a windows pc with a different locale). So I worry about locales and encoding of that passphrase not giving the same numerical representation. On the same computer or a computer with the same locale this does obviously not give a problem.

Therefore I would like to be able to fixed encode (and normalize?) and store as UTF-8. which is recommended here: http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html (point 4).

There are many issues relating to encoding/unicode/UTF-8/codepages I don't fully (or fully don't) grasp. I fiddled with boost:locale and boost::nowide, but couldn't figure it out or it doesn't work under windows (dunno). Some links with more clarification on the issues (windows) involved:

http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/

http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/

But these links address the opposite problem! How to make things look the same no matter what underlying representation, I need the same underlying [bit-wise] representation, no matter how it looks!

So the question is, how do I make sure (and do I have to?) that the locale/encoding has no effect on the basic data that get encrypted, data, as in the sense of an array of 8-bit integers? I don't necessarilly care about UTF-8 or Unicode, just need to be able to recover data, no matter what locale/encoding. The first link is helpful in explaining the issue.

Thoughts, C is not Unicode aware, would linking in some C-code help, or does C++ change that then again? Or will limiting input to "ASCII" characters (I know that doesn't exist on windows) ALWAYS, as in 'on any windows computer') work?

Accepted solution:

```
void EncryptFileNames ( const boost::filesystem::path& p, const std::string& pw );

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) // No checking
{
    // Call with encrypt.exe c:\tmp pässwörd

    boost::nowide::args a ( argc, argv ); // Fix arguments - make them UTF-8

    boost::filesystem::path p ( argv [ 1 ] );

    EncryptFileNames ( p, boost::locale::normalize ( argv [ 2 ], boost::locale::norm_nfc, std::locale ( ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to all contributers.

PS: For encryption I use Crypto++ with VS2008SP1 and Boost (without ICU backend).

Comment: Neither C nor C++ are Unicode aware, so linking some C code isn't going to make a difference. Of course OS libraries or third party libraries might be Unicode aware.

Comment: Well I have no experience with either of these libraries but I can see the code above is wrong. You must convert to UTF-8 before you try to normalize. From the boost::locale::normalize documentation 'Note: This function receives only Unicode strings, i.e.: UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. It does not take in account the locale encoding, because Unicode decomposition and composition are meaningless outside of a Unicode character set.'

Comment: Secondly `boost::locale::normalize` does not work in place. You must do something like `std::string arg2 = boost::locale::normalize (argv[2], ...);`

Comment: @ John But isn't the input (char **argv) UTF-16 as we are on windows?

Comment: No it will not be. It will use the local code page. `char*` data can never be UTF-16 since char is only 8 bits.

Comment: I think if you switch the order of nowide and normalize, and fix your use of normalize, then you might be on the right track.

Comment: @ John So if I just pass the char* (i.e. not pass a string) to the encryption function, the problem is solved? Like I said, no need to make sense, just a matter of numbers.

Comment: But you need consistent numbers don't you? The local code page will vary from one installation of Windows to another. I must admit I'm getting a bit confused about what you are after.

Comment: Code page is just the windows terminology for their encodings. They vary depending on where in the world the Windows installation is. So you do need to convert from the local code page to utf-8. And it seems nowide will do that for you, very simply. I'm afraid I don't know about boost and different locales but I would imagine that the default is OK. At this point you already have UTF-8 so the locale is probably just being used to convert utf-8 to unicode internally.

Comment: Changed code to accepted solution.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Firstly UTF-8 is a red herring. To be international you must use an international character set, there is only one worth considering and it's called Unicode. How you represent Unicode within your program (i.e. how you encode it) is up to you, as long as the encoding can represent all of Unicode there is no problem. You could pick UTF-8 but since you are working on Windows it seems reasonable to pick the encoding that Windows uses internally which is UTF-16. As bmargulies says you can use MultiByteToWideChar to get from the local representation (i.e. the local code page) to UTF-16. I don't see the need to do the extra step and generate UTF-8 from UTF-16 but if you wanted to do that you could use WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: The link in the question explains the need for converting with a fixed encoding.

Comment: @degski UTF-16 is a fixed encoding.

Comment: Do you mean this in the sense that on any windows computer with no matter what locale, f.e. 'ö' or 'ä' will always be (internally) represented with the same 2 bytes? The quoted article sais: "...two identical character strings may be represented with different byte sequences depending on the encoding being applied for translation (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, etc...)." I'm lost. I'm probably missing the point.

Comment: What I mean is that UTF-16 is a fixed encoding governed by international standards. And that Windows NT/XP/2000/Vista/7 all use UTF-16 internally (Windows 95/98/Me do not however).

Comment: Either choice, UTF-8 or UTF-16, is going to work. It's just that it's a little bit less work if you choose UTF-16 because its the encoding used by the operating system.

Comment: @john UTF-16 is not a fixed encoding at all. In UTF-16, codepoints are often 4 bytes and sometimes 2 bytes. For more details, search "fixed-width" in the http://utf8everywhere.org/ document

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky Fixed doesn't mean fixed width. I know UTF-16 is not fixed width, UTF-8 isn't fixed width either.

Comment: Unicode defines a set of standardized normalization rules that you can apply before passing any Unicode-encoded data to your encryption algorithms.  That ensures that any given character will always be represented the same way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  think at this point degski is just concerned with getting his data to be Unicode encoded. Normalization would be the next step.

Comment: Accepted, including comments elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is compiled with `_UNICODE`, then just call `WideCharToMultiByte` with the UTF-8 code page to get UTF-8. If your application is not compiled with `_UNICODE`, call `MultiByteToWideChar` to get UTF-16 from your ACP bytes, and then call `WideCharToMultiByte` to get UTF-8.

Since the code you added shows std::string, the data is presumably in the ACP for the system. So the recipe here will work. Now, there are plenty of convenience APIs for this purpose, such as `mbtowcs`. Don't be distracted by 'MB'. That's just Windows-speak for 'not UTF-16'.

Comment: Clarified question I hope. Does your solution achieve the objective? boost::nowide does achieve what you are suggesting in a very simple manner by the way http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/ I'm not sure it achieves what I need, as UTF-8 is also multibyte.

Comment: boost::nowide is a great thing. Much better than MultiByteToWideChar API, and more convenient in C++ code. Do you really care if it is multibyte or not, and why? It is a cookie - opaque data - for your use case.

Comment: @Pavel Radzivilovsky Yes, you're right, I don't care what it is, just that it [the opaque data] is the same on different computers with different locales.

Comment: @degski, so pick UTF-8 or UTF-16 whatever is most convenient for you, using whatever method is most convenient, I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: @degski, OK having looked over your post again, it think I see your concern. You don't know after you've got the input from the user whether that input has been 'internationalized' or not. Well I'm afraid the answer is 'it depends'. It depends on how you are getting the input from the user, and how you have compiled your application. So the only way to make progress would be to post some of your code.

Comment: @degski there is a reason why all internet uses UTF-8. Use what is more popular for platform-independent implementation. UTF-16 is a problem because it is endianness-sensitive.